# Trying to understand keyval.sty (specifically \KV@@sp@def)

Tags: macros, key-value

I'm confused by the following macro definitions in keyval.sty (Version from 02/2020, Lines 65ff):

```
\def\@tempa#1{%
\long\def\KV@@sp@def##1##2{%
  \futurelet\KV@tempa\KV@@sp@d##2\@nil\@nil#1\@nil\relax##1}%
\def\KV@@sp@d{%
  \ifx\KV@tempa\@sptoken
    \expandafter\KV@@sp@b
  \else
    \expandafter\KV@@sp@b\expandafter#1%
  \fi}%
\long\def\KV@@sp@b#1##1 \@nil{\KV@@sp@c##1}%
  }
\@tempa{ }
```

So `\KV@@sp@b` is given two delimiters in its parameter string: Namely `#1` (which is "initialized" as `<space>` in the last line) and `<space>\@nil`.

Line 3 calls `\KV@@sp@d` which ultimately expands to `\KV@@sp@b`. The confusing thing to me is how `\KV@@sp@b` is ultimately used in Line 3: It seems to me that if `\@tempa` is called with any other argument than `<space>` (let's say `\foo`), then Line 3 ultimately expands to `\KV@sp@b\foo<actualargument>\@nil\@nil\foo\@nil` - i.e. the second delimiter `<space>\@nil` is never encountered. Instead, `\foo` is inserted where (it seems to me) a `<space>` should be.

What am I missing? It looks to me like there's a bug there, but it seems to work fine?

Comment: The `\@tempa` thing is just a trick to get a space token in the definition. If you were to do `\long\def\KV@@sp@b<space>##1 \@nil{\KV@@sp@c##1}` (where `<space>` is an actual space) then TeX would ignore that when reading the input (because it ignores spaces after control sequences). Doing that trick with `\@tmpa` inserts the space _after_ the input is tokenized, so TeX won't ignore the space.

Comment: So `\@tempa` should definitely never be called with any other parameter again? Then my problem seems to be somewhere else entirely... thank you :)

Comment: Yes, that's right. As the name indicates, it's a temporary macro and is redefined as soon as you use some key-val for the first time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\@tempa` thing you see in that piece of code is just a trick to get a space token in the definitions.  That is necessary because when TeX is reading input it ignores spaces after multi-letter control sequences (like `\hello` and `\x`, but not like `\$` or active characters like `~`, assuming “usual” catcodes), so all of:

```
\def\tmp#1{}
\def \tmp #1{}
\def      \tmp      #1{}
```

will do the same thing because the spaces after `\def` and `\tmp` are ignored. However in the piece of code you show `keyval` needs some spaces in places where TeX would ignore them.  To have a space token in those places, a common trick is to define a temporary macro (here `\@tempa`) and use `#1` where you'd want a space, then you just need to use the temporary macro with the space as argument and all `#1` (*not* `##1`) will be replaced by the space token.

To illustrate, compare the output of:

```
1: Token is \meaning !

\def\tmpa#1{Token is \meaning#1!}
2: \tmpa{ }
```

> [image]

In `1` the space character after `\meaning` is ignored by TeX, and it effectively does `\meaning!` (and prints `the character !`), while in `2` the space is inserted after and TeX does `\meaning<space>`, printing `blank space`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez You are right, of course, thanks! I made my answer a bit more specific. One thing though: are active characters considered to be control sequences (not that the classification affects anything---just out of sheer curiosity)? In the TeXbook, Knuth says “Active characters behave like control sequences”, but I didn't find anything saying they _are_ or _are not_...

Comment: I already noticed your edit and removed my commernt. ;-) You are right and I messed things up: Chapter 3 (Controlling TeX) of the TeXbooks explains "control sequence" in the same way as you do: Two flavors: control word/control symbol. In TeXbook chapter 24: Summary of Vertical Mode, somewhere after exercise 24.5, you find: "Here *`<control sequence>`* denotes a token that is either a control sequence **or an active character**; *[...]*" So I overlooked the subtle difference between "control sequence" (words) and *`<control sequence>`* (Backus/Naur-notation of TeX's grammar).

Answer (score 6):

keyval.dtx says:

> `\KV@@sp@def{⟨cmd⟩}{⟨token list⟩}`
>   is like `\def`, except that a space token at the beginning or end of
>   `⟨token list⟩` is removed before
>   making the assignment.

Let's look at the code:

```
\def\@tempa#1{%
\long\def\KV@@sp@def##1##2{%
  \futurelet\KV@tempa\KV@@sp@d##2\@nil\@nil#1\@nil\relax##1}%
\def\KV@@sp@d{%
  \ifx\KV@tempa\@sptoken
    \expandafter\KV@@sp@b
  \else
    \expandafter\KV@@sp@b\expandafter#1%
 \fi}%
\long\def\KV@@sp@b#1##1 \@nil{\KV@@sp@c##1}%
  }
\@tempa{ }
[...]
\long\def\KV@@sp@c#1\@nil#2\relax#3{\KV@toks@{#1}\edef#3{\the\KV@toks@}}
```

Carrying out `\@tempa` with a `⟨space token⟩` [ nested in curly braces to ensure that the corresponding space-character in the .tex-input-file will not be skipped during tokenization but will yield an explicit space-token=an explicit character-token of character-code 32—32 is the number of the code-point of the space-character in TeX's internal character-encoding-scheme which with traditional engines is ASCII and with XeTeX-based/LuaTeX-based engines is unicode— and category-code 10(space) ] as argument yields:

```
\long\def\KV@@sp@def#1#2{%
  \futurelet\KV@tempa\KV@@sp@d#2\@nil\@nil⟨space token⟩\@nil\relax#1}%
\def\KV@@sp@d{%
  \ifx\KV@tempa\@sptoken
    \expandafter\KV@@sp@b
  \else
    \expandafter\KV@@sp@b\expandafter⟨space token⟩%
 \fi}%
\long\def\KV@@sp@b⟨space token⟩#1⟨space token⟩\@nil{\KV@@sp@c#1}%
[...]
\long\def\KV@@sp@c#1\@nil#2\relax#3{\KV@toks@{#1}\edef#3{\the\KV@toks@}}
```

This is how the macros which form the `\KV@@sp@def`-mechanism get defined.

How does the `\KV@@sp@def`-mechanism work?

```
\KV@@sp@def{⟨cmd⟩}{⟨token list⟩}
```

yields:

```
\futurelet\KV@tempa\KV@@sp@d⟨token list⟩\@nil\@nil⟨space token⟩\@nil\relax⟨cmd⟩
```

The sequence `\futurelet\KV@tempa`, which comes from expanding `\KV@@sp@def`, assigns  the meaning of the first token of `#2`/of `⟨token list⟩` to the control-word-token `\KV@tempa`.

Then `\KV@@sp@d` is carried out.

Basically `\KV@@sp@d` works as follows: If the meaning of `\KV@tempa` indicates that the first token of `⟨token list⟩` is a `⟨space token⟩`, then call `\KV@@sp@b`. Otherwise call `\KV@@sp@b⟨space token⟩`. The `\expandafter`s in `\KV@@sp@d`'s definition are needed to make the `\else` or the  `\fi` go away before `\KV@@sp@b` is carried out.

This way the next token behind the token `\KV@@sp@b` in any case is a `⟨space token⟩`. Either it is the first token of `⟨token list⟩` or it is prepended to `⟨token list⟩` by `\KV@@sp@d` because `⟨token list⟩` does not have a leading `⟨space token⟩`.

In other words: The cases of `⟨token list⟩` having a leading `⟨space token⟩` or not having a leading `⟨space token⟩` are settled by having `\KV@@sp@d` insert a leading `⟨space token⟩` in case `⟨token list⟩` does not have a leading `⟨space token⟩`.

When `\KV@@sp@d` and its `\ifx`-thingie are done, you in any case have something like this:

```
\KV@@sp@b⟨space token⟩⟨token list with a leading space token spliced off if at least one leading space token was present⟩\@nil\@nil⟨space token⟩\@nil\relax⟨cmd⟩
```

`\KV@@sp@b` itself is delimited by `⟨space token⟩`. Thus the `⟨space token⟩` behind `\KV@@sp@b` will be removed.

The argument of `\KV@@sp@b` is delimited by `⟨space token⟩\@nil`.

Thus you can fork two cases:

Case 1:

If `⟨token list with a leading space token spliced off if at least one leading space token was present⟩` has a trailing `⟨space token⟩`, the argument-delimiter will be formed by `⟨token list with a leading space token spliced off if at least one leading space token was present⟩`'s trailing `⟨space token⟩` and the `\@nil` right behind `⟨token list with a leading space token spliced off if at least one leading space token was present⟩` and you get:

```
\KV@@sp@c⟨token list with a leading space token and/or a trailing space token spliced off if at least one leading/trailing space token was present⟩\@nil⟨space token⟩\@nil\relax⟨cmd⟩
```

Case 2:

If `⟨token list with a leading space token spliced off if at least one leading space token was present⟩` does not have a trailing `⟨space token⟩`, the argument-delimiter will be formed by the `⟨space token⟩` before the third `\@nil` and that `\@nil` and you get:

```
\KV@@sp@c⟨token list with a leading space token and/or a trailing space token spliced off if at least one leading/trailing space token was present⟩\@nil\@nil\relax⟨cmd⟩
```

In both cases the first argument of `\KV@@sp@c`, which is delimited by `\@nil`, will be `⟨token list with a leading space token and/or a trailing space token spliced off if at least one leading/trailing space token was present⟩`,
the second argument of `\KV@@sp@c`, which is delimited by `\relax`, will be the stuff between the first `\@nil` and the `\relax`, and
the third argument of `\KV@@sp@c`, which is not delimited, will be formed by `⟨cmd⟩`.

Thus in both cases carrying out `\KV@@sp@c` yields:

```
\KV@toks@{⟨token list with a leading space token and/or a trailing space token spliced off if at least one leading/trailing space token was present⟩}\edef⟨cmd⟩{\the\KV@toks@}
```

You might ask the question:

Why assignment to the token register `\KV@toks@` and then  `\edef⟨cmd⟩{\the\KV@toks@}` instead of
`\def⟨cmd⟩{⟨token list with a leading space token and/or a trailing space token spliced off if at least one leading/trailing space token was present⟩}`?

The reason is:

`⟨token list with a leading space token and/or a trailing space token spliced off if at least one leading/trailing space token was present⟩` might contain hashes (`#`).
With `\def` these might erroneously be taken for something that in the `⟨balanced text⟩` of the definition of `⟨cmd⟩` denotes an argument while the `⟨parameter text⟩` of the definition of `⟨cmd⟩` is empty. This in turn would result in error-messages.
A subtlety of `\edef` is: When `\edef` gets the content of a token register via `\the⟨token register⟩`, then the tokens that form that content will not be expanded further. Besides this each explicit character token of category code 6(parameter), i.e., each hash (`#`), will be doubled and thus will not be taken for something that in the `⟨balanced text⟩` of the definition of `⟨cmd⟩` denotes an argument.

So on the one hand with the "token register-`\edef`-way" you have doubling of hashes within the `⟨balanced text⟩` of the definition of `⟨cmd⟩`. On the other hand: When macros—`⟨cmd⟩` is a macro—get expanded, two consecutive explicit character tokens of category code 6(parameter), i.e., two consecutive hashes (`##`), collapse into a single token/into a single hash (`#`). (This is useful when it comes to nesting  `⟨definition⟩`s within the `⟨balanced text⟩`s of `⟨definition⟩`s.)

The "token register-`\edef`-way" ensures that expanding `⟨cmd⟩` yields exactly the same amount/constellation of explicit character tokens of category code 6(parameter)/hashes as is provided in `⟨token list⟩`.

That's it.

---

The `\KV@@sp@def`-mechanism relies on `⟨token list⟩` not containing the token `\@nil`.

The `\KV@@sp@def`-mechanism removes exactly one leading `⟨space token⟩` from `⟨token list⟩` if present and exactly one trailing `⟨space token⟩` from `⟨token list⟩` if present before defining `⟨cmd⟩`, even if several leading and/or trailing `⟨space token⟩`s are present.

In case the set of tokens that forms `⟨token list with a leading space token spliced off if at least one leading space token was present⟩` is of pattern `{⟨balanced text⟩}⟨space token⟩`, the pair of curly braces that surrounds `⟨balanced text⟩` will be removed by `\KV@@sp@b`.

In case after carrying out `\KV@@sp@b` `⟨token list with a leading space token and/or a trailing space token spliced off if at least one leading/trailing space token was present⟩` is of pattern `{⟨balanced text⟩}`, the outermost pair of curly braces will be removed by `\KV@@sp@c`.

This means: Depending on the presence of a leading/trailing `⟨space token⟩`, up to two levels of surrounding curly braces might get removed/stripped off.  Whether such brace-removal is desired or not depends on the use-case.

---

By the way:

More about the removal of leading `⟨space token⟩`s and trailing `⟨space token⟩`s from macro arguments can be found in the solutions to [challenge 15 (Space removal)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/challenges/AroBend/AroundTheBend.pdf#chapter.15) of Michael Downes' *Around the Bend*-challenges.

Comment: +1: Also thanks for the `Around the Bend` information!